# In Drupal Fullcalendar, how do I add an additional field to the calendar view?

Tags: views, 7, entities, datetime, javascript

I need to add one more field to the Fullcalender views. Anyone know what code I need to edit to take care of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to edit any code to add additional field to calendar view.

To add additional field, you need to install [Views fields combine](https://drupal.org/project/views_fields_combine) or [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module.

**How to use Views fields combine:**

1. Edit your calendar view
2. Add fields you want to display (from field)
3. Add Combined fields field and select which fields you want to display
4. Under format -> settings -> customize fields, check **Use a custom title** checkbox and select the combined fields you created on step 3
5. Apply changes and save your view then preview the results on the actual page/block.

Comment: THANK YOU!! You have finally helped me fix this problem I have been having for months. This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: @ekorotkin glad it worked for you :)